# Pegar maior número de itens em uma matriz de lista em Python

Tags: python, lista, matriz

Eu tenho uma matriz em em Python composta por arrays. Mas esses arrays podem ter tamanhos diferentes. Por exemplo:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

O que eu quero saber é se existe um meio (alguma função pronta do python) que me retorne o tamanho do maior array dessa matriz.

Por exemplo:

```
x = funcao(matriz)
```

que retornaria para x o valor 6 (tamanho do array na posição 3 da matriz).

Answer (score 8):

Pode iterar a sua matriz criando um [generator](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generators) e usando um `len()` para pegar o tamanho de cada elemento, assim: `gen = (len(x) for x in matriz)` e daí usar a função `max()` para pegar o maior elemento do generator.

Exemplo:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
gen = (len(x) for x in matriz)
print(type(gen))
print(max(gen))
```

Saída:

> `<class 'generator'>`
>   6

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/fp155M)

Comment: Espera - quando eu votei tinha mais texto explicando o que você faz aí - não precisa da list comprehension, verdade, mas a explicação estava boa.

Comment: @jsbueno poisé, eu usei o list comprehension pois tinha imaginado algo mais complexo a princípio, mas é possível usar o max direto no generator da iteração, acha melhor que eu explique isso mais detalhadamente?

Comment: @jsbueno editei para explicar no passo a passo, o que achou?

Comment: T[a legala a explicação.

Answer (score 7):

Use max:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
len_maior = len(max(matriz, key=len)) # tamanho da maior sublista, 6
```

`max(matriz, key=len)` vai retornar a maior sublista (`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`), com base na sua `len` (tamanho), depois vamos de facto 'medi-la' e saber o seu tamanho (`len([1,2,3,4,5,6])`), que é 6 neste caso

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/w5Ch2U)

Comment: Muito bom! Python sempre me surpreendendo

Comment: @Math, key pode levar com metodos, inclusive tu podes faze-los usando lambda

Comment: Cool! +1 `max` parece bem desenhado!

Comment: (: Obagdo @JJoao

Answer (score 6):

Outra versão:

```
max(map(len,matriz))
```