# Obter sub-lista com o maior tamanho

Tags: python

Preciso criar uma função que receba uma lista aninhada e retorne a sub lista com o maior número de elementos desta lista aninhada. Como fazer?

```
lista_aninhada = [[10,20],[30,40,50],[19,29,9,49],[0]]
print(lista_aninhada[0])

def max_lista_aninhada(lista_aninhada):
  i=0
  for elemento in lista_aninhada:
    if len(lista_aninhada[i]) > len(lista_aninhada[i+1]):
      print("a")
      i=i+1

max_lista_aninhada(lista_aninhada)
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170186/112052

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `max` para retornar o maior elemento de uma sequência. Essa função aceita um argumento chamado `key` que define **qual a lógica que queremos utilizar** na hora de comparar elementos e definir qual é o maior.

Se passarmos o argumento `key=len` para `max`, a lógica para definir qual elemento é maior é dada pela função `len` - ou seja, os elementos são ordenados por tamanho e o maior deles é retornado.

Exemplo:

```
lista_aninhada = [[10,20],[30,40,50],[19,29,9,49],[0]]
maior_sublista = max(lista_aninhada, key=len)
print(maior_sublista)  # output: [19, 29, 9, 49]
```

Neste caso, cada sublista de `lista_aninhada` é entregue à função `len` e comparada com as demais. No fim, a sublista de maior tamanho é retornada.

Note que se houver empate (duas sublistas de mesmo tamanho), a sublista que aparecer primeiro na lista aninhada será retornada.